# VSCode IntelliSense error with NX / Angular IntelliSense "Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'"

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, nomachine-nx

We have a production Angular app that we're in the process of moving to a Monorepo with NX. So far we have everything working properly from dev to production with no issues.

However, in VSCode, basically every Angular directive (*ngFor, *ngIf, [routerLink], everything...) is erroring out and is  not recognized.

(Before you ask, yes: all modules (i.e.`CommonModule`, `BrowserModule` are properly imported in the `.module.ts` file)

***Like I said:* Everything works fine** when served locally and in production, including in our CI/CD pipeline: no errors. Lint, Test, and build also all work without issue... I suspect this is a VS Code, TSConfig, or Angular.json issue but I've been spinning my wheels for 2 days.

[image]

Possibly related is that all of the libraries are also not being picked up by VS Code:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Open the extension output window in VS Code and see if angular language service has thrown errors

Comment: @AluanHaddad No noticeable errors with Angular Language Service but I could see "Enabling View Engine language service for..."

This lead me into looking at the settings for the extension and found the answer... I'll post it now. Thank you so much for leading me down the path, I'm the Manager for the team and don't get into VS Code very often :-)

Comment: Glad I could be of service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with our settings for the Angular Language Service extension

The "Angular: View-engine" setting was set as Use legacy View Engine language service : true" which needs to be false for Apps using Ivy.

[image]